Defining an AAOS launcher that permanently hides system bars and overrides default boot screen
Hiding system bars has been asked several times already, but it didn't help me with my problem. I'm trying to write a launcher for AAOS targeting Android 14. Once the app is set as home app it should permanently hide all system bars and should also override the default boot screen when the system is reboot.
What already works:

Setting the app as home app hides system bars
System bars are not shown on touch or drag events

I'm still facing two problems:

When putting the emulator to sleep and waking it up again, the navigation bar is shown for a brief amount of time before it vanishes.
When doing an adb reboot the default boot screen is shown and my home app is only loaded after "Starting phone..." is finished.

Here's the minimal code of my app
AndroidManifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CarLauncher">
        <activity
            android:name=".CarLauncher"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="uiMode|mcc|mnc"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_car_launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

CarLauncher.kt
class CarLauncher : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        hideSystemBars(window, window.decorView)

        setContent {
            CarLauncherTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Column {
                        Clock()
                        Greeting(
                            name = "Android",
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)

        hideSystemBars(window, window.decorView)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        hideSystemBars(window, window.decorView)
    }

    private fun hideSystemBars(window: Window, decorView: View) {
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, decorView)
            .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Composable
fun Clock() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            TextClock(context).apply {
                textSize.let { this.textSize = 30f }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
    )
}

themes.xml
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.CarLauncher" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
</resources>

I already tried different things like

adding all sorts of permissions (taken from launcher found in Android source code)
listening to BOOT_COMPLETED and LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED to show my app instead of default boot screen
listening to ACTION_SCREEN_ON to immediately hide navigation bar when screen is woken up
using ActivityManager.moveTaskToFront
etc.

I'm running out of ideas how to achieve my goals. Any help is highly appreciated.

"should also override the default boot screen when the system is reboot" -- that is unrelated to a launcher on AAOS, just as it is on non-Automotive Android. AFAIK, you change the boot animation the same for AAOS as you would do for AOSP. "it should permanently hide all system bars" -- at most, a launcher can control this for the launcher itself. It cannot control this for the entire device, including other apps or system processes. You need to look into changing the SystemUI look-and-feel, AFAIK.

For now I would be happy when navigation bar is hidden (never shown) when device is woken up again.
